# How can the crystal foxes in "The Last Jedi" be living?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

How can the crystal foxes in *The Last Jedi* be living?

They're made of minerals and crystals, as far as we can see, so what holds them together? Is it the Force?

Comment: Star Wars doesn't abide by our understanding of physics and our definition of what makes a 'living creature'. That is the 'fiction' part in 'science-fiction'.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfTalQLQi3o

Comment: @Sava also, Star Wars is more fantasy than sci-fi. There isn't an attempt at science in most of the additions to the world.

Comment: @Sava:  I for one am shocked at the biological inaccuracies in these movies about magical space wizards.

Comment: @Centimane Not to mention the tropes and themes: rescuing the princess, one on one battles, mystical magic, heroes and villains, etc. All very fantasy-like.

Comment: And on top of all of that, there's plenty of fantasy biology. The old extended universe included space mantas, living crystals, mammals that underwent metamorphosis, multiple species who _grew_ starships, sapient trees, an organic equivalent to the Borg from Star Trek, space dragons with fusion reactors for stomachs, Hutts, and the Yuuzhan Vong. A vulpine species with crystals instead of fur isn't really that much of a stretch.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Now you've made we want to go and read the old extended universe!

Comment: I'm not the only person who saw these things and thought of carbuncles in Final Fantasy right?

Comment: Why do you assume that carbon-based biology is the only type possible? There is plenty of speculation - although I have only seen it in science fiction, so not sure if it is grounded in fact - that silicon-based life would be possible. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Magical space wizard _samurai._

Comment: @Centimane interesting: I've never considered the difference between sci-fi and fantasy being how much they try to describe their worlds using something that resembles our universe's science. Is there any thing I could read on differences between sci-fi and fantasy? it's got me thinking now

Comment: @MarkWhite From wikipedia: "Fantasy is distinguished from the genres of science fiction and horror by the absence of scientific or macabre themes respectively, though these genres overlap." I would argue that Star Wars lacks in scientific themes.

Answer (score 108):

I don't know the canonical answer, but flesh-and-blood creatures can have crystals growing off of their fur.

This is an image of a furry animal with ice crystals growing off of its fur:
[image: woof with ice crystals growing on fur]

It lives on a planet where it rains both liquid and crystal water, depending on temperature. 
**Edit** the first picture shows a creature with ice crystals that had actually precipitated and collected on its fur-- not ones that had grown there.

However, this creature has ice crystals growing off of its hair and clothing, because of the ambient air temperature around it, and the humidity it exudes from breathing:

[image: ----------]

Comment: Don't know who downvoted this, but it seems a perfectly good answer to how crystals could form on fur to create that effect. Nice idea!

Comment: It seems likely that the pictured hydrogen hydroxide crystals grew in the atmosphere of said planet and then 'rained' onto the pictured animal already in crystalline form. It is, however, possible on this same planet for liquid hydrogen hydroxide to fall from the sky and immediately crystallize onto whatever it hits on the surface - including animal fur - though, so +1. Also, the latter phenomenon can be highly unpleasant in large quantities, particularly when it crystallizes onto road surfaces and leaves and limbs of very tall plant life.

Comment: You might wish to note that this answer isn't especially accurate. The Vulptex has crystal fur, not fur coated with crystals.

Comment: @Valorum To be fair, your answer says nothing about it not having any sort of fur, or that the "bristles" are just made of crystal and not a combination of fur covered in a crystalline substance. If you're being pedantic, there's no reason your answers couldn't both be correct; there's not enough detail to make that assumption.

Comment: @Anoplexian - The [making of](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KfTalQLQi3o) video indicates that the crystalline structures extend *into* the creature

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86403/discussion-on-answer-by-user151841-how-can-the-crystal-foxes-in-the-last-jedi).

Comment: @Anoplexian - I've added some edits to reflect this. The film's VFX Creature guy says that their fur has **become crystalline** as a result of the Vulptex *consuming* the crystal salt

Comment: Coincidentally, there are also creatures on this planet you speak of that are [partially glass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexactinellid).

Answer (score 98):

The very short answer is that although the outer "fur" of the Vulptex is crystalline, the inner part of the animal appears to remain mundane flesh and blood.

> *"The theory is they’ve fed off this planet for so long that **their fur
> has become crystalline.** They’ve taken on the very surface of the
> planet they live on.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: New Revelations From Star Wars Creatures Boss [Neal Scanlon - SW Creature Workshop]](https://web.archive.org/web/20171031174135/https://www.empireonline.com/movies/star-wars-last-jedi/last-jedi-new-revelations-star-wars-creatures-boss/)</sup></sub>

and

> *Vulptices are foxlike creatures with **coats made up of crystalline
> bristles***
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Databank: Vulptex](https://www.starwars.com/databank/vulptex)</sup></sub>

---

The film's
[Visual Dictionary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_The_Visual_Dictionary) indicates that over time the animals have evolved to take advantage of their surroundings (and abundance of crystal salts) but there's no good indication that their physiology defies logic, any more than a snail does because it has an integument [made from metal carbonate](https://www.lenntech.com/periodic/elements/ca.htm).

[image]

> *But no, it wasn’t his imagination. There really were animals back there—dozens of them. They were small—not much higher than a person’s knee, with long, pointy ears and drooping whiskers framing their faces. Their bodies glittered in the transports’ lights, and **Poe realized what he’d thought was fur was actually a dense covering of crystal bristles**. When the creatures moved, their fur made a sound that reminded him of the wind chimes of distant Pamarthe.*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

---

Although not part of the official canon, you can see from the film's making-of VFX video that the crystals appear to project *directly from* the Vulptex's skin rather than simply being *coated onto* their fur.

Comment: Ah, it's a porcupine! I too thought it was a fox at first when I saw the film, but this shows again that appearances can be deceiving.